# Error when implementing WebRTC using Flutter InAppWebView (ParameterError)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application, flutter-inappwebview

I am building a mobile application using Flutter that can video call and audio call from mobile to web. But everytime I tried connecting to the web it will give the following error:

[image]

Below is the .dart code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class SIRAWeb extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SIRAWebState createState() => new _SIRAWebState();
}

class _SIRAWebState extends State<SIRAWeb> {
  late InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(
                          "https://opensys-sira.000webhostapp.com/"
                      )),
                      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                        _webViewController = controller;
                      },
                      androidOnPermissionRequest: (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin, List<String> resources) async {
                        return PermissionRequestResponse(resources: resources, action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                      }
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.